# Visual Studio 2015 - vcxproj.filters file occasionally becomes invalid XML

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Sometimes when working on a large solution, some projects lose all filters (and become a giant list of files instead). When checking the `.vcxproj.filters` file, it is indeed invalid XML. I then have to fix the problems manually and reload the project.

However, it is not cut off at the end - it is actually missing lines in the middle, which makes it unlikely to be an unexpected interruption while writing the file.

Here's what it currently looks like:

```
<ClInclude Include="plugins\FileName1.h">
  <Filter>plugins</Filter>
</ClInclude>
<ClInclude Include="utils\FileName2.h">
  <Filter>utils</Filter>
<ClInclude Include="otherfolder\FileName3.h">
  <Filter>otherfolder</Filter>
</ClInclude>
```

Note the lack of closing tag for `FileName2.h`.

What causes this to happen, and how to avoid it in the future?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused when using a merge tool that doesn't recognize the closing tag as a line that needs to be added. A merge tool sees the line `</ClInclude>` as already present in the target file, and so doesn't merge it.

I'm not sure of a fix beyond more careful merging now that you're aware of the problem.

Comment: Maybe not even an automated merge tool - this looks like someone messed up when dealing with a merge conflict or a rebase conflict.